# Framework that allows shared UI code between web and native app?

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Is there a framework out there that allows for the same UI code to give a web app, an iOS app (preferably native), **and** and Android app (preferably native)? I know there is Angular 2 with Ionic 2 but the mobile apps made this don't look as native as I'd like. Are there any other options that accomplish this?

I'm not looking to only reuse business logic between the different apps, but **reuse the actual UI code** too to minimize doubling up of coding effort. As I understand this would rule out React Native because UI code for the web apps and mobile apps will be separate.

Thanks! :)

Comment: you can try nativescript or xamarin

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Firebase? http://firebase.google.com You have most of your backend needs covered and the web is full of examples for native iOS, Android and web (Angular or other)